# Can you suggest to me an English Esperanto dictionary?

Tags: discussion

Writing English is not a problem for me. However I get stumped when English words I thought that in my thinking would be pronounced in this way, are pronounced in a totally different way.

One particular problem I face daily is the short 'i'  and long 'ii'. The dictionaries  I find online they have pronunciation guide in IPA which is too much for me, I also dont like their pronouncement buttons that produces the sound.

Is there a dictionary that lists the English words with their Esperanto counterparts. That would make my life very easy. I thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you after an English–Esperanto **translating** dictionary, or one which has the pronunciation in Esperanto-like words? I've no idea what sound "ii" is supposed to represent; is *liik* pronounced as the English *leek* or *like*?

Comment: "i" is "ee" sound. "ii" like "ai". If there is Esperanto after the English word, it will be very helpful to pronounce the word in the nearabouts  of the actual pronunciation. e.g. the word "genre" is actually pronounced somewhat like "zonra", "zonra" is nearabout the actual pronunciation of "genre". In that way it would be helpful without going  through the  weird IPA symbols. Boutique is actually pronounced as booteek (nearabout), body is pronounced as bodi, levy is pronounced as leevai, that way it would be very helpful to us.

Comment: If you google "esperanto resources" you'll get lots of information, although I can't vouch for specific dictionaries. But have you considered finding an English dictionary that uses a [simpler scheme for representing pronunciations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_notation_of_the_American_Heritage_Dictionary), such as [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=church)?

Comment: *Levy* isn't pronounced "leevai" at all (although the name Levi is). *Levy,* meaning a tax, is pronounced "levee". Frankly I think you'd be better off learning IPA.

Comment: re: "I also don't like their pronouncement buttons that produces the sound."... What is it you don't like about it? Is the sound too faint/bad audio? Is the accent (US vs UK) not one you want? Does the sound not match the letters you expect? Something else? Also, is it necessary to have an Esperanto to English dictionary with pronunciation for the English, or is it sufficient to have an Esperanto to English but no sound, and then use a regular English dictionary for pronunciation?

Comment: How is this a valid Meta question??

Comment: @Lambie For whatever reason, in the past the guideline was made for any kind of resource request to be asked on meta instead of main. It's definitely on-topic for ELU as a whole, but does seem a little weird on meta. But meta is where resource requests are supposed to be made and if they are made on main, then they are usually migrated to meta.

Comment: Can you **recommend** a [bi-lingual] dictionary ...? Google has useful [results for *genre pronunciation*](https://www.google.com/search?q=genre+pronunciation&oq=genre+pronunciation&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.6238j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) including an easy to understand phonetic spelling: **zhon** · ruh

Comment: and [boutique](https://www.google.com/search?q=boutique+pronunciation&hl=en&sxsrf=ALiCzsb_HCbx1ONPgbdrk9f7zhl_oJI_Ew%3A1667512266146&source=hp&ei=yjdkY_3PBdCJ9u8PqZWliAk&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAY2RF2s4_MnnTnUZejJOH2bU3g-f3xg7p&ved=0ahUKEwj93J2i_5L7AhXQhP0HHalKCZEQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=boutique+pronunciation&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzoHCCMQ6gIQJzoECAAQQzoECC4QJzoFCC4QgAQ6CAguEIAEENQCOg4ILhCABBDHARCvARDLAToICAAQgAQQywE6CggAEIAEEIcCEBRQkgdYsFpg4l5oAXAAeACAAcsBiAGyE5IBBjguMTMuMZgBAKABAbABCg&sclient=gws-wiz) = boo . **teek**

Comment: @Mitch Resources about the English language. Not just any language. I have always assumed.

Comment: @Lambie it is definitely about English. Also Esperanto. But definitely English. The mention of Esperanto is expected but not disqualifying.

Comment: @Mitch Bilingual dictionaries are not really "about English". But have it your way. I really don't care. :)

Comment: This isn't about Esperanto. It's about **showing the pronunciation of English** using non-standard (Esperanto) symbols.

Comment: @AndrewLeach "Is there a dictionary that lists the English words with their Esperanto counterparts" in my world, that is called a bilingual dictionary. It's possible the OP is a bit off track here if s/he thinks an Esperanto<>English dictionary will fix the issue of pronunciation.